# rebuild url with mvc bundle

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

On the website I'm building we are using the built in bundling and minification.
We render our scripts by using the `@Scripts.Render`

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/scripts")
```

it generates a link like:

```
bundles/scripts?v=3-DUUAAegZl4yp1O4V0VL0GnJ0U6gT3De8yKb41lfGs1
```

Here I thought that the hash:

```
v=3-DUUAAegZl4yp1O4V0VL0GnJ0U6gT3De8yKb41lfGs1
```

would be smart and change if we made changes to the inlcuded scripts but it seems like that is not the case.

Now when we are trying to implement a custom cdn for out bundling it fails on updates since the hash never seems to change.

Does anyone know of a solution to change the hash when the script changes or if we are doing something wring?

Edit:
I noticed that there is a difference in behavior depending on what environment I'm using.
Local development it seems to be working but it doesn't work on the staging server.
Should there be a difference?

Edit2:
Seems to be working as it should on production servers as well. Will have to do more research on what the cause can be.

Edit3:
Seem that the one causing the problem was in the registry LogRewrittenUrlEnabled  was set to false to allow url rewrites at the same time as using dynamic content compression (gzip) so will have to find another way to enable this

Comment: When you say "made changes to the included scripts" do you mean redeploy them, or dynamically change them?

Comment: I mean changing the sourcefiles. Like adding a new function to the js file. The function gets added but the bundle keeps the old hash that means that the cdn have no idea that it has been changed and keep serving the old one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that on the server we had in the registry

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\Rewrite /v LogRewrittenUrlEnabled set to false
```

And if you have that then the cache-buster hash is not refreshing when the content i bundle is changed.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, the cache-buster hash should change if you change the contents of a script. There's some useful information about how the cache for bundling works that may help you here [ASP.NET MVC Bundling cache. (Detecting css files changes) (internal behaviour)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18454897/asp-net-mvc-bundling-cache-detecting-css-files-changes-internal-behaviour).

Comment: Thank you, I've read about it and thought I give it a try on my local machine with vs development server and it seems to be working there but not on my staging machine. Might be a difference on how the development server works comparing to iis?

Comment: My guess is it's a caching issue. As a starting point, I'd try clearing both browser and server caches (recycle the app pool or restart IIS will clear the server cache).

Comment: I found the problem on the server we have HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\Rewrite /v LogRewrittenUrlEnabled set to false to allow url rewritting and filecompression at the same time. If I remove that registry entry then the hash is updating as it should. Now I will need to find a way to have url rewrite enabled with compression and the bundles hashes updating as they should