# mvc bundle and css management strategy

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, bundle

I developed a website, which can be used by different customers. As a result, we want to give different CSS styles and images to individual customers.

What we want is to manage CSS and images separately, so we won't need to deploy the site again just because we added some new CSS or images. As the site is under MVC, when accessing URLs such as:

```
www.mysite.com/customerA/myPage

www.mysite.com/customerB/myPage
```

we can find the customer id and find the right CSS and image to return.

The problem is that we want to bundle CSS, when the CSS or images are bundled, two issues will occur:

1. How the bundle detect underlying CSS file change? Is it possible?
2. Some users may already visited the URL and cached the bundled CSS, how can we disable the cached CSS, so it will get the new version?

Answer (score 3):

The .NET bundling strategy is very intelligent in solving both of your issues.  Once you create a bundle - example below:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));
```

And render this bundle out on your website, the output looks something like this:

```
<link href="/Content/css?v=xUfHQEnjwMk9UEexrvHPdvPxJduGrgz0bbI5qy5BGHY1" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Notice the `?v=bigTextstring`.  Anytime a file in your bundle changes, the bundling framework will change the bigTextString after the `?v=`.  So, for your first question, yes, it will automatically detect file changes.  You can get more information about how all of that process works if you visit [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18454897/asp-net-mvc-bundling-cache-detecting-css-files-changes-internal-behaviour?rq=1).  For your second question, the `?v=` parameter, when changed, signals the client's browser that this is a different file than you had, you need to download it again.

Comment: Hi Tommy, my MVC doesn't put this ?v=xUfHQEnjwMk9UEexrvHPdvPxJduGrgz0bbI5qy5BGHY1, only <link href="/Content/css" ref="...">. Do I need to config something?

Comment: @daxu - Are you running in debug mode? The bundles don't bundle when you are in debug mode or turn off EnableOptimizations in the BundleConfig file.

Comment: I build in release mode, there is no calling of EnableOptimizations and in web.config has <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" />. Still when I put this line:<link href="/Content/pdfcss" rel="stylesheet"/> it doesn't include version id.

Comment: @daxu - I have never seen a bundle render without the version query string.  How are you rendering the bundle in your view?  Are you using `@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")`?  Double check your code / bundle setup.  You may need to update your question with your bundle config and how you are rendering them in your view.

Comment: sorry, my bad, in deed it adds the version number. Will the bundle be updated if the physical location of the css file is on a share such as unc path like \\myshare\files\css\customerA.css?

Comment: @daxu - It should as its still a physical file, however, I have never pulled a CSS file from a network share for a website.  Run a quick test :)

Comment: The reason for the bundle not working was that I was trying a page which I render a view to string. The string will be feed into a html to pdf engine to get pdf out.

Answer (score 1):

Tommy has a great answer. I just wanted to elaborate on a few points.

First, as long as the bundle itself hasn't changed (added/removed scripts/styles or changed the location of those files), then you can freely update the files themselves without republishing the whole site. The bundler runs at runtime and looks at the last modified timestamp of the included files. If any of the files has changed, a new bundle will be generated with an updated cache-busting querystring param.

However, since the actual bundle configuration is code-based, if you add/remove items from the bundle or change the location of the file(s), such that you have to update the bundle configuration in `BundleConfig.cs` then you *must* republish, or at least also update the project DLL. This is because the code compiled within that DLL has changed.